# 'The' combination vs. 'a' combination

Tags: articles

Our current house color is the combination of beige and gray, but I'd like to pick a different one.
Our current house color is a combination of beige and gray, but I'd like to pick a different one.

Which is correct?

Comment: The second is correct, using "a" as there are many possibilities. I would say "pick different colours" or "pick a different scheme" as it is unclear what "one" refers to. One of the colours, or a different combination of the same colours, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Using "the" with a singular object implies that you are identifying a unique item - *the* city called New York, *the* bottle over there. If you are not identifying one thing then you should use "a".

There can be more than one combination of beige and gray - it could be beige and dark grey, or beige and light gray, or stripes or squares of beige and gray.

So you should use "a".

Comment: Even with well-defined colors, different ratios will give you a different result.  I.e. there are "combinations" of beige and dark grey.

Comment: +1. You'd reserve *the combination* for a specific combination.  *Our house is the combination of blue and grey that our paint store recommended for warding off nesting condors.*